# boost::spirit 1.53 multi_pass iterator related compilation error

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-qi

**The code:**

```
typedef std::string::const_iterator iterator;
namespace parsers
{
    namespace spirit = ::boost::spirit;
    namespace ascii = ::boost::spirit::ascii;
    namespace phoenix = ::boost::phoenix;
    spirit::qi::rule< iterator, void(std::string), ascii::space_type > action_parser = 
        '"'
        > spirit::qi::lit("action")
        > spirit::qi::labels::_r1
        > '"';
}
```

**Errors:**

```
> 1>CL : warning : This header is deprecated. Please use:
> boost/spirit/include/classic.hpp
> 1>D:\CPP\boost\boost_1_53_0\boost_1_53_0\boost/spirit/home/support/iterators/multi_pass_fwd.hpp(59):
> error C2976: 'boost::spirit::multi_pass' : too few template arguments
> 1>D:\CPP\boost\boost_1_53_0\boost_1_53_0\boost/spirit/home/support/iterators/multi_pass_fwd.hpp(86):
> error C3203: 'multi_pass' : unspecialized class template can't be used
> as a template argument for template parameter 'Iterator', expected a
> real type
> 1>D:\CPP\boost\boost_1_53_0\boost_1_53_0\boost/spirit/home/support/iterators/multi_pass_fwd.hpp(86):
> error C2955: 'boost::spirit::multi_pass' : use of class template
> requires template argument list
> 1>D:\CPP\boost\boost_1_53_0\boost_1_53_0\boost/spirit/home/support/iterators/multi_pass_fwd.hpp(86):
> error C2977: 'boost::spirit::traits::is_multi_pass' : too many
> template arguments
> 1>D:\CPP\boost\boost_1_53_0\boost_1_53_0\boost/spirit/home/support/iterators/multi_pass.hpp(183):
> error C2976: 'boost::spirit::multi_pass' : too few template arguments
> 1>D:\CPP\boost\boost_1_53_0\boost_1_53_0\boost/spirit/home/support/iterators/istream_iterator.hpp(37):
> error C2955: 'boost::spirit::multi_pass' : use of class template
> requires template argument list
```

Comment: I suppose you know you do have the correct number of template arguments where appropriate and you don't understand why you're getting the errors?

Comment: [C2976](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t1kaz6a.aspx), [C3203](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/606k9xxc(v=vs.80).aspx), and more generally [Build Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x5x43k7(v=vs.80).aspx) should help.

Comment: There's an official example: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/mini_xml___asts_.html. Yes, the template arguments provided for the rule are correct according to the examples.

Comment: Which headers do you include?

Comment: // SYSTEM
#include <vector>
#include <string>
// PROJECT
#include <boost/spirit.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
// LOCAL
#include "sqlite3.h"

Answer (score 2):

> **Q.:** I removed the boost/spirit.hpp inclusion. Why was it the reason? P.S. Thx to FoReVer

**A.:** It was the reason because

> CL : warning : This header is deprecated. Please use: 
>   
> > boost/spirit/include/classic.hpp

In other words: it told you exactly why. And this translates into normal life as "just because".

Now onto why the developers would *deprecate* old headers:

> Wikipedia **[Deprecation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation)**
>
> Deprecation is a status applied to a computer software feature, characteristic, or practice indicating it should be avoided, typically because of being superseded

And there you have it: "typically because of being superseded". In this case, SpiritV2 superseded SpiritV1 around 2009 (?). This is what the documentation says about it:

> [Spirit Classic](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/what_s_new/spirit_1_x.html)
>
> > The Spirit V1.8.x code base has been integrated with Spirit V2. It is now called Spirit.Classic. Since the directory structure has changed (the Spirit Classic headers are now moved to the $BOOST_ROOT/boost/spirit/home/classic directory), we created forwarding headers allowing existing applications to compile without any change.
> >
> > However, these forwarding headers are deprecated, which will result in corresponding warnings generated for each of the headers starting with Boost V1.38. The forwarding headers are expected to be removed in the future.
> >
> > The recommended way of using Spirit Classic now is to include header files from the directory $BOOST_ROOT/boost/spirit/include. All Spirit Classic headers in this directory have 'classic_' prefixed to their name.

All in all, it just means: Spirit Classic is OLD. Don't use it.

In case you have inherited a Spirit V1 parser and need guidance on migrating to Spirit V2:

- **[Porting from Spirit 1.8.x](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/notes/porting_from_spirit_1_8_x.html)**

Note: SpiritX3 is already under development as we speak. See [here](http://boost-spirit.com/home/2013/02/23/spirit-x3-on-github/)

Answer (score 0):

I removed the boost/spirit.hpp inclusion.
Why was it the reason?

Courtesy FoReVer